# String text.getText(0) returns null in java XWPF

Tags: java, xwpf

Hi I have a code that accept input from a user then the program process it and transfer it into Microsoft word, the problem is when I use a debugger the String text returns null even though I called the getText function from the XWPFRun class,
here's the sample code that I have written:

```
    @FXML
    private void handlePrintButtonAction() {
        try {
            //Part where it reads and manipulates the content inside the indigency 
            String IndigencyPath = "C:\\Users\\aliya\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\leng\\cagbaby\\BrgyCert\\Indigency.docx";
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(IndigencyPath));

            //User input data is retrieved and assigned to the string variables
            String residentFirstName = firstNameField.getText();
            String residentMiddleName = middleNameField.getText();
            String residentLastName = lastNameField.getText();
            String residentSuffix = suffixField.getText();
            String residentAge = ageField.getText();
            String residentZone = zoneField.getText();
            String residentBarangay = barangayField.getText();
            String residentMunicipality = municipalityField.getText();
            String residentProvince = provinceField.getText();

            //Iterates to every paragraph of the document to replace with the actual resident data
            for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : document.getParagraphs()) {
                List<XWPFRun> runs = paragraph.getRuns();
                if (runs != null) {
                    for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
                        String text = run.getText(0);

                        //Method to replace placeholders with actual user-inpu personal data
                        if (text != null) {
                            if (text.contains("<<ResidentFirstName>>")) {
                                text = text.replace("<<ResidentFirstName>>", residentFirstName);

                            }
                            if (text.contains("<<ResidentMiddleName>>")) {
                                text = text.replace("<<ResidentMiddleName>>", residentMiddleName);

                            }
                            if (text.contains("<<ResidentLastName>>")) {
                                text = text.replace("<<ResidentLastName>>", residentLastName);

                            }
                            if (text.contains("<<ResidentSuffix>>")) {
                                text = text.replace("<<ResidentSuffix>>", residentSuffix);

                            }
                            if (text.contains("<<ResidentAge>>")) {
                                text = text.replace("<<ResidentAge>>", residentAge);

                            }
                            if (text.contains("<<ResidentZone>>")) {
                                text = text.replace("<<ResidentZone>>", residentZone);

                            }
                            if (text.contains("<<ResidentBarangay>>")) {
                                text = text.replace("<<ResidentBarangay>>", residentBarangay);

                            }
                            if (text.contains("<<ResidentMunicipality>>")) {
                                text = text.replace("<<ResidentMunicipality>>", residentMunicipality);

                            }
                            if (text.contains("<<ResidentProvince>>")) {
                                text = text.replace("<<ResidentProvince>>", residentProvince);
                            }
                            run.setText(text, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Print button clicked");

            //Document with the personal data is inputted in a temporary file
            File temporaryFile = File.createTempFile("resident_cert", ".docx");
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(temporaryFile);
            document.write(outputStream); //flushes data sa docx
            outputStream.close();

            //Opens the document in the default app MICROSOFT WORD
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(temporaryFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Handle any exceptions that occur during the process
        }
    }
```

Im expecting that the string text is not equal to null